# Uploading html5 canvas content using ajax on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-canvas, blob, image-uploading

For a webbased application we want to be able to let people sign on an Ipad.running IOS 
We use a canvas element to draw on and then upload it to an IBM I Service.running net.data 
It works fine on  chrome and firefox on a pc.

on an ipad in safari or chrome though the request seems to be empty.
I am searching for hours and don’t seem to be able to find out what is wrong with this code.

Does anybody Know Who I Could Fix this?
We are not using jquery by the way.
belowe is part of the code we use

thanks!
j.v.

```js
GUI.Signature.dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI) {
  var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);;
  var array = [];
  var content = null;
  for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  content= new Uint8Array(array);
  return new Blob([content], {type: 'image/jpeg'}); 
};


GUI.Signature.send = function(){
  if(!GUI.Signature.isEnabled()){return;}
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var dataURL = GUI.Signature.canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);
  var blob = GUI.Signature.dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
  var fd = new FormData(GLOBAL.activeForm);
  var fsUri = GLOBAL.activeForm.action.replace("MAIN","UPLOAD");

  fd.append("signature", blob);
  fd.append("blobName","signature" );

  request.open('POST', fsUri, false);
  request.send(fd);

};
```

Comment: Just updated the IOS to 6.0.1
Now I do get an object on the server. If I opend it in an text editor it shows: [object Uint8Array] so I am wondering if the atob is causing the problems?

Comment: A new day and a clean head. 

I found out the problem is in the Blog constructor

When you pass an Uint8Array
To A Blob constructor it does not work on ios for some reason 
The size of the blog is reduced to 19 
When you open the file that is uploaded in an text editor you see:

[object Uint8Array]

Not sure, maybe Blob does a toString of the Uint8Array and this is not correctly implemented
In either Blob or the Uint8Array

Does anybody knows a work around?
I have seen a work around that uses 

I think I post a second question for this more specific problem.

Comment: there seems to be a reported bug in webkit [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165907) unfortunatly it has  a Status:  WontFix So Hopefuly it will be beter in a new release of chrome or safari for ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is indeed appending the Uint8Array tot the Blob object. 
Wrapping the Uint8Array  in an ArrayBuffer solves the problem

it was answerd  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340989/blob-does-not-accept-uint8array-on-ios/14389983#14389983)